# Findpeaks function misses peaks for an unknown reason

Tags: r, ggplot2

I’ve got some data that I’m trying to locate the peaks in. It’s got 23 peaks, which are visible in the data. However, the findpeaks function only seems to be able to identify 21 of them, but I can’t work out why.

I’d be very grateful for some help debugging and picking up the last two peaks.

```
data <- data.frame(time = c(1669, 1670, 1671, 1672, 1673, 1674, 1675, 1676, 1677, 1923, 
                            1924, 1925, 1926, 1927, 1928, 1929, 2176, 2177, 2178, 2179, 2180, 
                            2181, 2182, 2428, 2429, 2430, 2431, 2432, 2433, 2434, 2435, 2687, 
                            2688, 2689, 2690, 2691, 2692, 2693, 2694, 3202, 3203, 3204, 3205, 
                            3206, 3207, 3208, 3209, 3730, 3731, 3732, 3733, 3734, 3735, 3736, 
                            3737, 3738, 4258, 4259, 4260, 4261, 4262, 4263, 4264, 4265, 4266, 
                            4267, 4268, 4269, 4789, 4790, 4791, 4792, 4793, 4794, 4795, 4796, 
                            4797, 4798, 4799, 4800, 5325, 5326, 5327, 5328, 5329, 5330, 5331, 
                            5332, 5333, 5334, 5335, 5336, 5337, 5849, 5850, 5851, 5852, 5853, 
                            5854, 5855, 5856, 5857, 5858, 5859, 5860, 5861, 6096, 6097, 6098, 
                            6099, 6100, 6101, 6102, 6103, 6104, 6105, 6106, 6107, 6108, 6109, 
                            6110, 6354, 6355, 6356, 6357, 6358, 6359, 6360, 6361, 6362, 6363, 
                            6364, 6365, 6366, 6367, 6857, 6858, 6859, 6860, 6861, 6862, 6863, 
                            6864, 6865, 6866, 6867, 6868, 6869, 6870, 6871, 6872, 7346, 7347, 
                            7348, 7349, 7350, 7351, 7352, 7353, 7354, 7355, 7356, 7357, 7358, 
                            7359, 7360, 7361, 7362, 7816, 7817, 7818, 7819, 7820, 7821, 7822, 
                            7823, 7824, 7825, 7826, 7827, 7828, 7829, 7830, 7831, 7832, 7833, 
                            7834, 7835, 7836, 8264, 8265, 8266, 8267, 8268, 8269, 8270, 8271, 
                            8272, 8273, 8274, 8275, 8276, 8277, 8278, 8279, 8280, 8281, 8282, 
                            8283, 8284, 8695, 8696, 8697, 8698, 8699, 8700, 8701, 8702, 8703, 
                            8704, 8705, 8706, 8707, 8708, 8709, 8710, 8711, 8712, 8713, 8714, 
                            8715, 8716, 9091, 9092, 9093, 9094, 9095, 9096, 9097, 9098, 9099, 
                            9100, 9101, 9102, 9103, 9104, 9105, 9106, 9107, 9108, 9109, 9110, 
                            9111, 9460, 9461, 9462, 9463, 9464, 9465, 9466, 9467, 9468, 9469, 
                            9470, 9471, 9472, 9473, 9474, 9475, 9476, 9477, 9478, 9479, 9799, 
                            9800, 9801, 9802, 9803, 9804, 9805, 9806, 9807, 9808, 9809, 9810, 
                            9811, 9812, 9813, 9814, 9815, 9816, 9817, 9818, 9819, 10102, 
                            10103, 10104, 10105, 10106, 10107, 10108, 10109, 10110, 10111, 
                            10112, 10113, 10114, 10115, 10116, 10117, 10118, 10119, 10120, 
                            10121, 10122, 10123, 10124, 10377, 10378, 10379, 10380, 10381, 
                            10382, 10383, 10384, 10385, 10386, 10387, 10388, 10389, 10390, 
                            10391, 10392, 10393, 10394, 10395, 10396, 10397, 10398, 10399, 
                            10400),
                   peak=c(698, 1022, 1369, 1514, 1510, 1298, 993, 726, 526, 820, 1177, 
                          1418, 1495, 1327, 1000, 705, 860, 1222, 1499, 1531, 1349, 1031, 
                          707, 538, 874, 1176, 1379, 1380, 1204, 893, 621, 550, 841, 1172, 
                          1402, 1472, 1324, 1025, 732, 750, 1043, 1277, 1380, 1313, 1117, 
                          859, 624, 707, 966, 1192, 1325, 1314, 1201, 1002, 756, 542, 500, 
                          626, 734, 875, 982, 1058, 1045, 981, 860, 739, 621, 500, 500, 
                          622, 767, 908, 1011, 1082, 1110, 1061, 975, 836, 701, 564, 538, 
                          677, 823, 969, 1061, 1117, 1129, 1091, 1038, 902, 779, 645, 525, 
                          583, 699, 837, 929, 1020, 1050, 1062, 1059, 996, 904, 802, 681, 
                          576, 530, 636, 749, 864, 954, 1032, 1084, 1108, 1080, 1018, 944, 
                          850, 747, 637, 526, 566, 665, 755, 852, 908, 983, 1009, 1006, 
                          976, 918, 848, 757, 669, 577, 532, 618, 709, 787, 873, 934, 992, 
                          1004, 996, 972, 919, 848, 753, 679, 592, 514, 566, 636, 722, 
                          786, 860, 905, 935, 962, 949, 943, 906, 859, 795, 729, 650, 563, 
                          501, 502, 552, 640, 702, 763, 841, 895, 945, 992, 1022, 1043, 
                          1050, 1045, 1024, 961, 902, 838, 775, 706, 622, 555, 502, 582, 
                          652, 724, 798, 871, 938, 974, 1035, 1053, 1066, 1079, 1055, 1015, 
                          985, 927, 863, 764, 718, 637, 545, 542, 618, 689, 761, 818, 892, 
                          934, 988, 1005, 1037, 1030, 1022, 1001, 969, 930, 875, 813, 752, 
                          680, 628, 557, 501, 511, 578, 625, 688, 743, 786, 825, 854, 887, 
                          903, 916, 894, 884, 871, 825, 791, 747, 696, 632, 582, 525, 525, 
                          576, 637, 672, 718, 746, 789, 830, 822, 828, 835, 831, 802, 781, 
                          743, 697, 661, 625, 551, 515, 548, 597, 643, 694, 754, 792, 830, 
                          866, 874, 889, 890, 896, 862, 849, 818, 771, 739, 684, 625, 570, 
                          517, 524, 573, 632, 698, 736, 797, 848, 877, 898, 941, 948, 943, 
                          944, 916, 893, 881, 823, 792, 749, 696, 648, 588, 541, 504, 559, 
                          626, 671, 712, 764, 818, 844, 864, 906, 915, 920, 929, 912, 889, 
                          857, 838, 796, 767, 712, 656, 627, 569, 534),
                   colour="red")

library(pracma)
peaks <- data.frame(findpeaks(data$peak, npeaks=23, threshold=100, peakpat = "[+]{1,}[0]*[-]{1,}", sortstr=TRUE))
data$n <- seq(1,length(data$peak))
data <- merge(x=data, y=peaks, by.x="n", by.y="X2", all.x=TRUE, all.y=TRUE)

ggplot(data, aes(x=time, y=peak, fill=colour, colour=colour)) +
  geom_col(orientation="x") +
  geom_point(aes(x=time, y=X1))
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `findpeaks`  , as you notice, accepts a `threshold` value which will affect the number of locations deemed to be peaks, and a `peakpat` pattern overriding `nups` and `ndowns` .

The criteria for visually finding a peak may well differ from whichever algorithm you choose to run -- there are others besides `findpeaks` -- to extract local maxima.

### new update

I contacted the maintainer (Hans Borcher) ; here's his response and explanation.

> In the given example, the use of `threshold=100` causes this
> phenomenon of "lost peaks". The 'threshold' is the difference between
> the peak and both valleys surrounding it. In the case of the two peaks
> very near to each other the valley between them is too high up and the
> peaks will not get counted. I see the problem for the user. The
> documentation shall make it clearer what 'threshold' really means and
> what the implications are when used.

Alternatively, consider: your data are noisy.  It's often helpful to first run a smoothing algorithm such as `loess` or `lowess` (there are hundreds of smoothers and spline-fitters out there) to get rid of spikiness before trying to find local maxima.

Comment: Thank you, the missed peaks are at *time= 9470s* and *time=10112s*. The problem appears to be that both are double peaks. At 9470s there's another slightly smaller peak at 9467, and at 10112s there's another slightly smaller peak at 10114s. I can't work out how to modify the *peakpat* to accommodate this and would be grateful for some help!

Comment: @Mike  i'll  see if I can fine-tune the parameters one of these lunch-breaks.

Comment: Dear @CarlWitthoft, have you ever considered that there could be a bug? I thought it would have been appropriate, instead of suggesting 'dumping', to suggest to send in a bug report. How will R packages improve, if not by reporting failures -- where have the good ol' habits gone?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in `findpeaks` with the `threshold` parameter. If you set this to `0` you will find all 25 peaks.

```
findpeaks(data$peak, peakpat = "[+]{1,}[0]*[-]{1,}",
          threshold = 0, npeaks = 0)
```

And setting `minpeakdistance = 5` will return the 23 peaks you were looking for (at least I hope so).

I assume a corrected `findpeaks` function will be provided with the next version of the package.

PS:
I don't think this is a Q&D tool. I know it has served well for a lot of users. Of course, there may be better and more reliable peak finding functions in other packages.

Comment: great find!  You should email this to the maintainer of the `pracma` package.

Comment: Turns out to be weak documentation of the parameter "threshold" rather than an outright bug.  See my edited answer